# dojo JsonRest call not working

Tags: dojo, jsonreststore

I'm trying to call my RESTful service from dojo. All I can see from debugger is, it tries to call the service but it doen't reach there. There are no errors. I can see the 'hello' alert.

```
    define(["dojo/store/JsonRest","dojo/domReady!"],
       function(JsonRest){
             alert("Hello");
             var rest = new JsonRest({
                target: "/my/rest/call"
              });
       }
);
```

I's following [this page](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/store/JsonRest.html#dojo-store-jsonrest) from dojotoolkit.

But if i call using a `declare` then it works.

```
define(["dojo/store/JsonRest","dojo/_base/declare","dojo/domReady!"],
       function(JsonRest, declare){
            var rest = declare(JsonRest);
            var restResult = new rest({
                target: "/my/rest/call"
            }); 
       }
);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

error messages in console:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're not following that tutorial to the letter. The difference is that you're using `define` and not `require`. Dojo's `define` is used in combination with `declare` to create new Dojo classes. Dojo's `require` is used to load and use existing classes. The link below is a recommended read and in your case pay special attention to the 'Requiring modules' and 'Defining modules' parts:

https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/modules/

If you use `require` like in that tutorial, it works perfectly:

```
require([
    'dojo/store/JsonRest',
], function(
    JsonRest
) {

    new JsonRest({
        target: 'some/resource/'
    }).get(1).then(function (item) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(item));
    });

});
```

Here's a working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZhsO67BFpWB5Txqy0Zl9?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, but in my case it's still not working. Is there any problem with spring bundled dojo and require?

Comment: Nope, there shouldn't be any problem. No console errors?

Comment: i've added the console screen in my original post